# jQuery ajax issue with search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on the functionality of searching images in a ajax based `div` which is also loading the data in a `div` container.

I have the following code and it works fine, if I am not executing any search criteria. If I add search, it throws error in all browsers in jquery min.js file. I am using version 1.11.1 for this. Different browsers show different errors.

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#finder").blur(executeFunction);
    function executeFunction(page) {
        page = typeof parseInt(page) == "number" ? page : 1;
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "find.php",
            data: {
                page: page,
                search: encodeURIComponent( $('#finder').val() )
            },
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                {
                    $("#container").html(msg);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    executeFunction(1);
});
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="finder" id="finder" />
```

Without search all work fine..

Here is the error I received in Firefox:

```
TypeError: 'initUIEvent' called on an object that does not implement interface UIEvent.

...unction(a,b){var c,d=[],e=function(a,b){b=m.isFunction(b)?b():null==b?"":b,d[d.l...
```

Chrome Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery-latest.min.js:4e jquery-latest.min.js:4Vc jquery-latest.min.js:4Vc jquery-latest.min.js:4Vc jquery-latest.min.js:4Vc jquery-latest.min.js:4Vc jquery-latest.min.js:4Vc jquery-latest.min.js:4m.param jquery-latest.min.js:4m.extend.ajax jquery-latest.min.js:4loadData (index):112m.event.dispatch jquery-latest.min.js:3r.handle
```

Opera Error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

every time i search, the error counter is increasing with same error message

IE 11 Error:

```
Argument not optional
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try recreating this issue just a hunch.

```
typeof parseInt(page) == "number"
```

The above statement is always true. If page is event-object the parseInt of page is NaN which will return true for the above statement.

I think the following will be better

```
$("#finder").blur(function(e) {
   executeFunction(1);
});
```

Other things.

You are binding one instance of following ajaxCompleteEvent every time an ajax request complete. In other words the result is being written to the page multiple times.

```
      $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
            $("#container").html(msg);
      });
```

Why don't you simply use

```
$("#container").html(msg);
```

in its place?

Comment: +1 for all "bad" code parts. And hanging more and more `.ajaxComplete()` handlers indeed can cause all kind of troubles.

Comment: so you guys are saying i should remove the ajaxcomplete code, well, it will not harm the code if i remove right. why this code has been provided by jquery then

Comment: success: function(msg) will allow you to do all that you want when this ajax request completes. OTOH .ajaxComplete() when bound to the document will trigger when any ajaxCall completes within the page [not just this one]. It is added to be bound to the page on document.ready